# "Property 'writeContract' does not exist on type" when using viem

Tags: typescript

Whenever I call writeContract on WalletClient, I get this error in typescript on vscode( image below):

```
Property 'writeContract' does not exist on type '{ account: Account<`0x${string}`> | undefined; batch?: { multicall?: boolean | { batchSize?: number | undefined; wait?: number | undefined; } | undefined; } | undefined; cacheTime: number; ... 10 more ...; extend: () => const; }'.ts(2339)
```

My understanding is that its not defined on the WalletClient type. But I am not sure. Has anyone else faced a similar issue?[image]

Comment: Can you share the code where you created the walletClient and publicClient?